# How to measure this angle?

Tags: wood, carpentry

I have scoured the internet and forum and I’m certain I’m over thinking this, but how can I measure this angle?

I’ve tried using a level and find the plum, but the board will still come out wrong. Help! [image]

Comment: There are tools that will copy angles, usually just two straight edges joined with a pivot point.  There are also angle finders.  Then there is math and measurement which hurts.

Comment: Couldn't you just use your phone?

Comment: there are two angels there, the horizontal and the vertical plane. Which one are you referring to ?

Comment: For what purpose do you need to know the exact angle? There are loads of ways of measuring this, the right one depends on what you want to do with said information.

Comment: *"the board will still come out wrong"* What board? Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: you don't need to measure the angle ... cut the end of the board square ... slide the board into position so that it touches the ceiling at top corner ... measure the gap between bottom corner and the ceiling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a level and peice of paper to trace angle and transfer to peice
[image: capture]
[image: transfer]

Answer (score 3):

Lots of ways. But without any special tools beyond either a ruler and some math (I know, that's a 4-letter word) or a [protractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protractor):

- Take a piece of cardboard and line it up with the angle and tape it to the wall.
- Use a level to draw a horizontal line from any point on the angle to the other side of the cardboard.
- Use a level to draw a vertical line from the any point on the angle (i.e., the edge of the cardboard up against the angle) down through the horizontal line.
- Remove the cardboard from the wall.
- Use a protractor to measure the angles of the triangle, or
- Measure the lengths of the sides and use math to calculate the angles of the triangle.

And actually, you don't even have to look up the math or understand it. You can go to a [right triangle calculator](https://www.calculator.net/right-triangle-calculator.html) and plug in the lengths of the sides of the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the orange lines are the board you're wanting to put on the wall, and have it match the angle of the ceiling so it fits snugly....  Use a level on the horizontal board to make sure it's level, hold it to the wall, and butt it up to the ceiling, as in your picture.  (yes, there will be a triangular gap below where the horizontal board touches the ceiling, but that's ok for now)  Then get another board (or even a piece of rectangular sturdy cardboard) and put it against the ceiling, laying on top of the horizontal board.  Then draw a line along the non-wall edge of the board at the ceiling angle, to transfer the exact angle of the ceiling onto the horizontal board.  Then the angle will then be perfect to cut along on the horizontal board and have it match the ceiling angle perfectly.

No measuring or fancy math needed.